# Distribute overstock to understocked stores

Tags: excel, vba, loops, conditional-statements

I have task.

A retail company has 10 stores (across columns) and 6000 different items (down rows) for sale.
Each item is understocked at some stores and overstocked at others.
For each item, I totaled the overstock and understock across all stores.

For items where the total understock is more than the total overstock, I want to distribute overstock to the understocked stores.
The distribution has to stop once there is nothing left to distribute.

I need a code which drops a value (stock) in each cell, across 10 columns/stores, then comes back to the first column to drop some more and continues across the columns until the total dropped reaches the total available.

Below is the code I have thus far (the dynamic cell refs repeat the code down all rows of the spreadsheet i.e. for the different items stocked).
I tried to create a running total of the amount dropped thus far across all stores (defined as the variable z).

The Do Until loop continues past the condition.
I want the condition to be checked inside the loop body and to stop if the condition is met.

My questions:

1. What is wrong with my Do Until loop?
2. Is there a way to check the condition during the loop body not at the start/end?
3. Is there another way of solving this? If using solver, please guide me which solver code to use (solverok, solveradd etc.) and what the various arguments should be set at.

```vb
Sub Stock_Transfers()
Dim x As Integer
Dim z As Double

For x = Range("A4").Row To Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row

Do Until z = 318
Cells(x, 74).Value = Cells(x, 74).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 74).Offset(0, -45).Value ' where Cells(x,74).Offset(0,-45).Value refers to a column which contains the corresponding store's sales/month and Range("BZ2").Value refers to a cell which contains a proportion of the month e.g. 0.25 so Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 74).Offset(0, -45).Value = 0.25 of one month's sales.
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 75).Value = Cells(x, 75).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 75).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 76).Value = Cells(x, 76).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 76).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 77).Value = Cells(x, 77).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 77).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 78).Value = Cells(x, 78).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 78).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 79).Value = Cells(x, 79).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 79).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 80).Value = Cells(x, 80).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 80).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 81).Value = Cells(x, 81).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 81).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 82).Value = Cells(x, 82).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 82).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Cells(x, 83).Value = Cells(x, 83).Value + Range("BZ2").Value * Cells(x, 83).Offset(0, -45).Value
z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(x, 74), Cells(x, 83)))
Loop

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Your way of loop creation assumes that a `z` value is mandatory to be exactly `318`. Are you sure that such an amount is obtained during the loop ** for every `x`**? Since you do not use that `z` in any way I cannot understand anything about how you try accomplishing what you try explaining that it should. Maybe a picture of the sheet trying to process, explaining the meaning of its columns will be more helpful...

Comment: In real life, the stores have different sales of each item per time periode (e.g. weekly, monthly). Do you need to consider this or do you just need to evenly distribute the total of each item across the stores? Is the total sales (per item, per time periode ) known in your table? Actually there's too many open questions, please provide an example as others already requested.

Comment: @TomBrunberg - for ease of explanation i have fixed the value of total sales at 318 (as i mentioned in my explanation above). in reality, its a dynamic cell reference but to keep the rest of the problem simple, i have fixed it for this example at 318. 
Also, each store has a sales per month figure for each item (referenced as Cells(x,74).Offset(0,-45).Value. This value is multiplied by Cells("BZ2") which refers to a cell containing a proportion of the one month's sales to drop into each store with each loop.

Comment: @FaneDuru - i had to create a variable z which calculates the running total of the stock dropped into the stores. it is the variable against which the limiting condition is set.  
I have watched the code run and yes it calculates the running total z after dropping a little stock (calculated as Cells ("BZ2").Value*Cells(x,74).Offset(0,-45).Value) into each store (Cells (x,74), Cells (x, 75) etc.). My problem is that it continues adding stock to each store even after the running total (z) has breached its limiting condition (set at 318 for the sake of eg)

Comment: @FaneDuru - i can't give a picture of the sheet, too many columns for it to fit in a screenshot

Comment: @TomBrunberg - So in the first round, you drop off 0.25 * sales/month in each column, and if the total after each drop (z) is less than the overstock, then you go to the next store or loop back to store one and add 0.25*sales/month and look at the total again (z). I have clarified this by adding a note in the code 
To simplify my question: 
1. Can a Do Until, Loop check the condition while inside the loop body or only at the beginning/end of each loop? 
2. For an 'Equal To' condition, can the code stop before it reaches that condition if it can't exactly equal that condition?

Comment: In a `DO {UNTIL or WHILE} .. LOOP` the check for continuation is done only once per loop cycle, at the beginning. But you can add checks at any point, and call `EXIT DO` if you want to exit the loop prematurely, immediately. E.g. `if stock = 0 then Exit Do`

Comment: With ref to a comment you addressed to @FaneDuru, You can and actually should provide a [mre] with your questions. It is typically extremely simplified (reduced) to only replicate the problem you are having, but still representative enough that an answer will help you. In current case a table with less than 10 columns and a few rows ,would probably be enough to show the issue. Further in this case the column headers would have been important for understanding.

Comment: @TomBrunberg - thank you for the insight. I will edit the question with a simpler code if i can otherwise will post a new question.

Comment: @TomBrunberg - i tried your suggestion i added 
`if z = 318 then
exit do
end if`
after each calculation of z. however, the loop still continues past z = 318

Comment: Maybe your termination condition (`=318`) never hits exactly, since it is `double`. Try with e.g.  `>317`

Comment: @TomBrunberg - ok i'm making some progress. i amended the code to add `if z>318 then exit do end if` and i reduced the incremental addition of stock with each loop from 0.25 of a month's stock to 0.033 of a month's stock so that i can get as close to the limiting condition as possible.

Comment: But can you really increase the stock with partial items? Maybe they should be counted with integers, or longs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not trying to follow the logic of how you re-distribute stock  - this is just to show how you can exit as soon as your 318 criteria is met:

```vb
Sub Stock_Transfers()

    Const STORE_COUNT As Long = 10
    Const COL_STORE_1 As Long = 74
    
    Dim x As Long, rw As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim z As Long 'or Double if you need fractional values..
    Dim col As Long, c As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some other sheet...
    
    For x = ws.Range("A4").Row To ws.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row
        Set rw = ws.Rows(x)
        Do While z <> 318 'or (eg) `Do While Abs(z-318) > 0.05` if you need fractional numbers
            For col = COL_STORE_1 To COL_STORE_1 + STORE_COUNT
                Set c = rw.Cells(col)
                c.Value = c.Value + ws.Range("BZ2").Value * c.Offset(0, -45).Value
                z = WorksheetFunction.Sum(rw.Cells(COL_STORE_1).Resize(1, STORE_COUNT))
                If z = 318 Then Exit For
            Next col
        Loop
nextProduct:
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: @TomBrunberg - good point: I didn't notice that declaration

Comment: thank you for your reply! yours is a much cleaner code. Your code was looping continuously (presumably because of the z = 318 condition) therefore i made the following changes:
1. do while < 318; instead of <>318 and 
2. if z>318 then exit for; instead of if z = 318 then exit for

However, this code skips certain rows. Any idea what could be the reason?

However, in

Comment: You're using `ws.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Row` which can be impacted by empty cells in the middle of the data.  Something like `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` would be more reliable.

Comment: Hi @Tim. That doesn't solve the problem. An example of a problem row: the total understock is 1,957 and the total overstock is 1,261. The sales/month of the different stores (ie c.Offset(0,-45).Value) are 353.67,184.25,90.17,118.50,184.25,113.83,3.33,42.08, 44.50, 182.08. I did a manual calculation and i get an answer but there is no reason why the code shouldn't work :(

Comment: I don't have your data, or a clear idea of exactly what the expected outcome would be.  If you can share a workbook with sample "before" and "after" data I can take a look.

Comment: How do i share that? I am new to this forum, so please guide me.

Comment: Any location such a box/Dropbox/google drive etc is fine